# Count with group by multiple column

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find stastistics of my website, I want to know how many unique views are there in a day and from which tier country.

I am doing this way.

There are two columns `ip` and `tier` from which I need to fetch counts

Column `ip` has ip of visitors.

Column `tier` has values as int `1,2,3,4,5` for `tier1,tier2,tier3,tier4,tier5 countries` respectively.

I need to fetch counts of unique ip's and then get respective tiers counts

```
$date1 = "4-3-2016 00:00:00";
$date2 = "5-3-2016 00:00:00";
$today = strtotime("midnight", strtotime($date1));
$nextday = strtotime("midnight", strtotime($date2));
$query="
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS `unique`
FROM `stats` 
WHERE (`date`>='$today' AND `date`<'$nextday')  
GROUP BY `ip`, `tier` ORDER BY `tier` DESC;
";
```

This give me output as

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1411 [type] => 0 )
```

I am getting ony unique counts from this, I need to get tiers count too.

There is this approch too

```
//adding in main query to get tiers counts
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `tier` = '1' THEN `ip` END) `tier1`
```

But this is slow, I want to do it by group by if its possible.

Please suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: try 

    `GROUP BY  tier, ip`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza still same result

Comment: show sample data and expected result. But direct on sql, no need complicate things adding php

Comment: Store dates as dates.

Answer (score 0):

This would give you count of unique ips respective to tier

```
SELECT tier, COUNT(ip) AS IP_COUNT FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT tier, ip 
FROM stats
WHERE <your conditions>) A
GROUP BY tier
```

The total count of ips would be the total sum of all IP_COUNT